# Running BICS datasync Job: Failure detected. Please check log file.

Tags: oracle, cloud, business-intelligence, obiee

I am unable to find this issue.

I am using BICS Datasync v2.2, When I was running the Job at that time 522 rows were uploaded out of 15036 rows.

Failure Detected. Please check log file.

Then I read the following thread:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3797380

There the result was "There is an issue in Column mapping", So I tried to check column mapping, But my column mapping is precise.

What am I supposed to do?? Please guide me?

```
START OF JOB

--------------------------------------------
51  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:34:36.504 IST  Starting ETL Process.
62  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:34:56.962 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing task INSERT_ONLY_DATA_COPY INSTANCE 1
MESSAGE:::
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.execution.exceptions.ExternalProcessException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ExternalExecutorTask.doExecute(ExternalExecutorTask.java:180)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.run(GenericTaskImpl.java:691)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.taskmanager.XCallable.call(XCallable.java:63)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
63  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:34:56.962 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing : EXTERNAL EXECUTOR TASKCR_W_YEAR_D_FROM_Source: INSERT_ONLY_DATA_COPY : (Source : FULL Target : FULL)
MESSAGE:::com.siebel.analytics.etl.execution.exceptions.ExternalProcessException: 
EXCEPTION CLASS::: java.lang.RuntimeException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:572)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.run(GenericTaskImpl.java:691)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.taskmanager.XCallable.call(XCallable.java:63)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: CAUSE :::
MESSAGE :::
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.execution.exceptions.ExternalProcessException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ExternalExecutorTask.doExecute(ExternalExecutorTask.java:180)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.run(GenericTaskImpl.java:691)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.taskmanager.XCallable.call(XCallable.java:63)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
64  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:34:56.966 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing task External Executor Batch
MESSAGE:::Submitted task failed during execution
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.submitIncompleteTasks(ParallelTaskBatch.java:512)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:670)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:636)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
65  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:34:56.967 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing : com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch:External Executor Batch
MESSAGE:::com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException: Submitted task failed during execution
EXCEPTION CLASS::: java.lang.RuntimeException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:572)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:636)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: CAUSE :::
MESSAGE :::Submitted task failed during execution
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.submitIncompleteTasks(ParallelTaskBatch.java:512)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:670)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:636)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
66  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:34:56.985 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing task All Task Batches
MESSAGE:::Execution of child batch External Executor Batch failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:650)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
67  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:34:56.986 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing : com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch:All Task Batches
MESSAGE:::com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException: Execution of child batch External Executor Batch failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: java.lang.RuntimeException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:572)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: CAUSE :::
MESSAGE :::Execution of child batch External Executor Batch failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:650)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
68  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:34:57.19 IST  Finishing ETL Process.
69  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:34:57.19 IST  MESSAGE:::Some steps failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.etl.engine.bore.SomeSessionsFailedException

com.siebel.etl.engine.bore.NewDispatcher.execute(NewDispatcher.java:263)
com.siebel.etl.engine.bore.NewDispatcher.run(NewDispatcher.java:123)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
71  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:35:02.993 IST  
--------------------------------------------

END OF JOB

--------------------------------------------
23  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:40:41.564 IST  Oracle Business Intelligence Cloud Service Data Sync (2.2.1), build: 11.1.1.10.0-2.2.1.20161205.1915
24  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:40:41.565 IST  The System properties are: GLOBAL_LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY_FOR_THIS_RUN D:\BICS\log\RECUVA-Job1.24879304
java.runtime.name Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin
java.vm.version 25.40-b25
java.vm.vendor Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator ;
ETL_EXECUTION_MODE ETL_SERVER
java.vm.name Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg sun.io
user.country IN
user.script 
sun.java.launcher SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level Service Pack 1
java.vm.specification.name Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir D:\BICS
java.runtime.version 1.8.0_40-b26
java.awt.graphicsenv sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\endorsed
os.arch amd64
java.io.tmpdir C:\Users\AKSHAY~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\
line.separator

java.vm.specification.vendor Oracle Corporation
user.variant 
os.name Windows 7
sun.jnu.encoding Cp1252
java.library.path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\akshay.bhan\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin;;.
java.specification.name Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version 52.0
sun.management.compiler HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version 6.1
user.home C:\Users\akshay.bhan
user.timezone Asia/Calcutta
java.awt.printerjob sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
file.encoding Cp1252
java.specification.version 1.8
java.class.path .\dacx.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derby.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_cs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_de_DE.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_es.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_fr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_hu.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_it.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_pl.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbynet.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyoptionaltools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyrun.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbytools.jar;
user.name akshay.bhan
java.vm.specification.version 1.8
sun.java.command com.siebel.analytics.etl.concurrentetl.ETLProcess EXECUTION_PLAN_NAME=RECUVA-Job1 ETL_PROCESS_ID=24879304 LAST_RUN_STATUS=Failed HONOR_TIME_LAGS=false ORIGIN_OF_REQUEST=null
java.home C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
sun.arch.data.model 64
user.language en
java.specification.vendor Oracle Corporation
oracle.security.jps.config D:\BICS\conf\security/jps-config-jse.xml
awt.toolkit sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info mixed mode
java.version 1.8.0_40
java.ext.dirs C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
sun.boot.class.path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\classes
java.vendor Oracle Corporation
file.separator \
java.vendor.url.bug http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.io.unicode.encoding UnicodeLittle
sun.cpu.endian little
sun.desktop windows
sun.cpu.isalist amd64

25  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:40:41.566 IST  Logging Started
26  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:40:41.568 IST  -Xmx value: -Xmx2048m
Max heap memory in MBs: 2048
29  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:40:45.382 IST  Credentials don't exist: map=oracle.dac.mail key=userCredEnc.
30  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:40:45.382 IST  Cannot get Email Password. Run the ServerSetup again!Credentials don't exist!
Make sure the properly configured cwallet file is used.
31  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:40:54.945 IST  
--------------------------------------------

START OF JOB

--------------------------------------------
33  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:41:36.545 IST  Starting ETL Process.
44  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:41:44.47 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing task INSERT_ONLY_DATA_COPY INSTANCE 1
MESSAGE:::
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.execution.exceptions.ExternalProcessException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ExternalExecutorTask.doExecute(ExternalExecutorTask.java:180)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.run(GenericTaskImpl.java:691)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.taskmanager.XCallable.call(XCallable.java:63)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
45  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:41:44.471 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing : EXTERNAL EXECUTOR TASKCR_W_YEAR_D_FROM_Source: INSERT_ONLY_DATA_COPY : (Source : FULL Target : FULL)
MESSAGE:::com.siebel.analytics.etl.execution.exceptions.ExternalProcessException: 
EXCEPTION CLASS::: java.lang.RuntimeException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:572)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.run(GenericTaskImpl.java:691)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.taskmanager.XCallable.call(XCallable.java:63)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: CAUSE :::
MESSAGE :::
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.execution.exceptions.ExternalProcessException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ExternalExecutorTask.doExecute(ExternalExecutorTask.java:180)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.run(GenericTaskImpl.java:691)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.taskmanager.XCallable.call(XCallable.java:63)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
46  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:41:44.474 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing task External Executor Batch
MESSAGE:::Submitted task failed during execution
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.submitIncompleteTasks(ParallelTaskBatch.java:512)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:670)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:636)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
47  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:41:44.475 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing : com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch:External Executor Batch
MESSAGE:::com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException: Submitted task failed during execution
EXCEPTION CLASS::: java.lang.RuntimeException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:572)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:636)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: CAUSE :::
MESSAGE :::Submitted task failed during execution
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.submitIncompleteTasks(ParallelTaskBatch.java:512)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:670)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:286)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:636)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
48  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:41:44.493 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing task All Task Batches
MESSAGE:::Execution of child batch External Executor Batch failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:650)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
49  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:41:44.493 IST  
ANOMALY INFO::: Error while executing : com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch:All Task Batches
MESSAGE:::com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException: Execution of child batch External Executor Batch failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: java.lang.RuntimeException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:572)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: CAUSE :::
MESSAGE :::Execution of child batch External Executor Batch failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.FailedTaskException

com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecuteNormal(ParallelTaskBatch.java:650)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.ParallelTaskBatch.doExecute(ParallelTaskBatch.java:200)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.doExecuteWithRetries(GenericTaskImpl.java:513)
com.siebel.analytics.etl.etltask.GenericTaskImpl.execute(GenericTaskImpl.java:406)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.executeTasks(Session.java:755)
com.siebel.etl.engine.core.Session.run(Session.java:876)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
50  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:41:44.515 IST  Finishing ETL Process.
51  SEVERE  2017-04-21 12:41:44.515 IST  MESSAGE:::Some steps failed.
EXCEPTION CLASS::: com.siebel.etl.engine.bore.SomeSessionsFailedException

com.siebel.etl.engine.bore.NewDispatcher.execute(NewDispatcher.java:263)
com.siebel.etl.engine.bore.NewDispatcher.run(NewDispatcher.java:123)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
53  GLOBAL  2017-04-21 12:41:49.253 IST  
--------------------------------------------

END OF JOB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

The column mapping that is matching of column's between source and target.

Following are the columns which are not mapped during mapping.

```
DSYS_BATCH_ID
DSYS_PROCESS_ID
DSYS_INSTANCE_ID
```

So we need to delete these columns from Target Mapping.